# Is there any way to loop an array from a specific key in php

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

Let I have an array like this

```
Array
(
    [126] => pitch
    [134] => pithc2
    [155] => pithc3
    [87]  => pithc4
    [45]  => pithc5
    [192] => pithc6
)
```

Now is there any way to apply loop in this array from specific key?
Example: I want to output after `155` then output look like

```
1. pitch4,
2. pithc5
3. pithc6
```

if I want get output after `45` then output look like

```
1. pithc6
```

Comment: Why did you delete your old question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/28804242/3933332

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

Here I use [`reset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php), [`next()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.next.php), [`current()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php), [`key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php), [`end()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) to loop through the array as you want it

```
<?php

    $arr = array(126 => "pitch", 134 => "pithc2", 155 => "pithc3", 87  => "pithc4", 45  => "pithc5", 192 => "pithc6");
    $from = 134;

    //Get last element + rest the array
    $end = end($arr);
    reset($arr);

    //set array pointer to '$from'
    while(key($arr) != $from) next($arr);


    while(current($arr) != $end) {

        next($arr);
        //prints the current array element and goes to the next one
        echo current($arr) . "<br />";

    }

?>
```

Output:

```
pithc3
pithc4
pithc5
pithc6
```

And if you want to limit how many elements should be printed you can use this:

```
<?php

    $arr = array(126 => "pitch", 134 => "pithc2", 155 => "pithc3", 87  => "pithc4", 45  => "pithc5", 192 => "pithc6");
    $from = 134;
    $howmany = 6;

    //Get last element + rest the array
    $end = end($arr);
    reset($arr);

    //set array pointer to '$from'
    while(key($arr) != $from) next($arr);

    //go through '$howmany' times
    for($i = 0; $i < $howmany; $i++) {

        //prints the current array element and goes to the next one
        echo current($arr) . "<br />";

        //rest the array to the beginning, while it reached the end
        if(current($arr) == $end)
            reset($arr);
        else
            next($arr);

    }

?>
```

Output:

```
pithc2
pithc3
pithc4
pithc5
pitch6
pithc
```

Comment: @Md.SahadatHossain (didn't copied the entire code now it works)

Comment: Using `end`, followed by `prev` might be better, if you know that the key from which the loop must start is known to exist. But that's micro-optimization anyways

Comment: How if i only want to list specific array keys, exp. 126,155,45 ?, thanks before